Change the order of the fill between different groups ggplot2
 library(ggplot2)
 library(dplyr)

 series <- data.frame(
      time = c(rep(1, 4),rep(2, 4), rep(3, 4), rep(4, 4)),
      type = c(1984:1987),
      value = rpois(16, 10)
    )
    
    
    series %>%
      ggplot(aes(time, value, group=factor(type, levels=1987:1984)))+
      geom_col(aes(fill= factor(type)))+
      guides(fill=guide_legend(title="type"))

I want to reorder the order of the fill between different groups, like the figure below that I have edited in Paint. How can I do that?

edit:

For time 1, I want to have the order 1984, 1985, 1986, and 1987.
For time 2, I want to have the order 1984, 1986, 1985, and 1987.
For time 3, I want to have the order 1984, 1985, 1987, and 1986.
For time 3, I want to have the order 1987, 1986, 1985, and 1984.


Have you tried setting the levels in fill = factor(type, levels = c(1984, 1987, 1985, 1986)) to see if it works?

I want to have different factors for different groups. So for 1) I want one order and another for 2) etc.

Is there some logic behind the different factor level orderings?

In this plot, no. In my real, more complicated code, it is that I have three proportions that sum up to 100 % and I want to show them in a different, specific order.

Then please give us some test data and  (simple) code that more accurately reflects your use case. We don’t need you complicated code - just the data frame you want to plot, a ggplot pipeline that gets you close to what you want, and a description of what is missing.

@Limey Okay, I have added some text to be clearer of what I want to do. I want to be able to manually adjust the order of the year over the four time periods.

A rather hacky solution which consists of creating a new factor column that you can manually order for each time and type based on the order you want them to appear in. You then use this to colour the bars, define all levels in the new factor with the same type to have the same colour, and then remove extra elements from the legend:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1234)
series <- data.frame(
  time = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 4), rep(4, 4)),
  type = c(1984:1987),
  value = rpois(16, 10)
)

# set order of variables for each time point
plot_data <- series |>
  mutate(
    type = factor(type),
    lvl = paste0(time, "-", type),
    lvl = factor(lvl, levels = c(
      c(
        "1-1984", "1-1985", "1-1986", "1-1987",
        "2-1984", "2-1986", "2-1985", "2-1987",
        "3-1984", "3-1985", "3-1987", "3-1986",
        "4-1987", "4-1986", "4-1985", "4-1984"
      )
    ))
  )

# set colours to use
col_palette <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(
  n = length(unique(plot_data$type)),
  name = "Dark2"
)
names(col_palette) <- unique(plot_data$type)
cols_to_plot <- plot_data |>
  select(lvl, type) |>
  left_join(tibble::enframe(col_palette),
    by = c("type" = "name")
  ) |>
  select(lvl, value) |>
  tibble::deframe()

# plot
plot_data |>
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = lvl)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = cols_to_plot,
    breaks = c("1-1984", "1-1985", "1-1986", "1-1987"),
    labels = c("1984", "1985", "1986", "1987"),
    name = "type"
  )



You can simplify by mapping lvl on the group aes: ... + geom_col(aes(fill = type, group = lvl)) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2").

I can't see a simpler way to reordering the types within different times than this.

It is a hack, but yeah it works. Thanks.

One thing: How can I use scale_fill_identity instead of scale_fill_manualwith this hack?

If you want to use scale_fill_identity, you would need to add the colours as a column in the data set and map fill to that column inside aes().
